# pandas dataframe giving weekly average to daily data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a daily price of a stock in pandas.dataframe format with a datetimeindex. and I want to have a column showing the average of the closing price of the week. I don't know how to explain it in text. This is how it show look like. Please tell me how can I get the column of "Weekly Average Close". Thanks!
[example in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJeST.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime.week()` to get the week_number for that date and assign that to a new column. Then, `df.groupby("week_number")["Close"].mean()` this will give you the weekly average close.